# Tensorflow - TypeError when using tf.cond()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Below is the snippet I have used in Tensorflow 2.6.0

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), batch_size=None)
x1=tf.keras.Input(1, dtype=tf.int32)
y = tf.cond(tf.less(x1,5), lambda :tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x), lambda :tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x))
model=tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[x,x1], outputs=[y])
model.summary()
```

> Error:
> python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py",
> line 969, in convert (str(python_func), type(x)))

> TypeError: To be compatible with tf.eager.defun, Python functions must return zero or more Tensors; in compilation of <function  at 0x7fe4743fde60>, found return value of type <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>, which is not a Tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `tf.cond` will not work with `KerasTensors` (tensors that are returned by `Keras` layers). You could try wrapping `tf.cond` in a custom layer:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class ConditionalActivationLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

  def call(self, inputs):
    x1, x = inputs[0], inputs[1]
    return tf.cond(tf.less(x1,5), lambda :tf.nn.relu(x), lambda :tf.nn.leaky_relu(x, alpha=0.1))

x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), batch_size=None)
x1= tf.keras.Input(1, dtype=tf.int32)
y = ConditionalActivationLayer()([x1, x])
model=tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[x,x1], outputs=[y])
model.summary()
```

```
odel: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_6 (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_5 (InputLayer)           [(None, 224, 224, 3  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conditional_activation_layer (  (None, 224, 224, 3)  0          ['input_6[0][0]',                
 ConditionalActivationLayer)                                      'input_5[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Also works with:

```
return tf.cond(tf.less(x1,5), lambda :tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x), lambda :tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x))
```

It is just a matter of taste.

You could also disable eager execution and it should work, since the input layers are now normal tensors:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), batch_size=None)
x1=tf.keras.Input(1, dtype=tf.int32)
print(type(x1), type(x)) #<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
y = tf.cond(tf.less(x1,5), lambda :tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x), lambda :tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x))
model=tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[x,x1], outputs=[y])
model.summary()
```

Comment: Wrapping tf.cond in customer layer works. Why isn't it working directly?

Comment: `tf.cond` works with tensors and not KerasTensors, basically what your error message is saying. It occurs because Eager Execution is on by default. If you take it off, your code will work (but normally you do not what to take it off)

Comment: I have tried with disabling eager execution and also, saved the model with model.save(). While loading and running with model.predict seeing below error 

Error:

Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed. while building NodeDef 'tf_op_layer_cond/cond/then/_0'

Comment: Where is the error coming from exactly? I do not see any model.save() or model.predict() in your question.

Comment: When running model.predict([x,x1], batch_size=1). After saving the model and while loading and running seeing above error. This was not mentioned in my question. I just tried it now.

Comment: Ok but don't you think this is out of the context of your original question? There could be many reasons for why it is not working and it is hard to answer them in the comments.